# Is there a way to change color of a highchart graph by clicking on the line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi I am plotting my graph using highchart and I want to know if there is any way you could change the color of the line plotted by clicking on the line and change it with a color picker or something. I don't want to change it from the options with series.color. I want to let the user change it according to his likeness. Thank you.

**Update**

A chart like this : [Line Graph Example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=6f47f6508dba44a10266ae24ec80ab4120b34345-1587468663-0-AfoT5cZNToHwtNs1sXRg8G9jZXOTbpgl5Kf5bgpenYzrFESFGC9a01uV58h0pI9Md9N_dY1t7Tqw-hJ2OlS06zF_SjFjD_-hJ92hekOWPhH7S86RRiCnZNTjf7vCLxjyVuxMBDS_wP5pKEpRv4Nmhn_Ru42tKWurse8XjFuDE08a7XvxZvEqwYLRitPzv7m5dA-Pq0zU1Vgnrm_nru1y9O7oiA3uIJa0gWf8ZylRWUk5zdiXUBRxNLwpmdQKyxeI2gV_V8wJcj6zvA0mVSTs-atgLdx1aZDSSasVK_atScszhePTJegfsBI8wk--YLzemjOQdX0hE4xdzBwQAxajLE3zz9du7l6qCf9wm0u9Q4kc)

Comment: Hi @Amal, Could you describe more precisely which line you want to change the color?

Comment: If there are multiple splines on a graph I need to let the user decide the color of the line by clcking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a click event function you can update the series with a color that is taken from some input, for example:

```
plotOptions: {
  spline: {
    events: {
      click: function() {
        this.update({
          color: $('#colorInput').val()
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qgmfzkju/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update